# Filebeat - Single Line Logs - No newline Character

Tags: logging, elastic-stack, filebeat

Filebeat documentation is very clear that logs not ending in a newline character will not be processed by filebeat: [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/newline-character-required-eof.html)

I do however have a number of logs which are written as single JSON objects, in a single line, which do not terminate with a newline character. I am unable to change the logger to add this newline character.

Has anyone found any solutions to forcing filebeat to read this lines which do not terminate with a newline character?

'close_eof = true' or multiline options don't appear to work, and I believe it's the line isn't read into the buffer until the newline character is read? So it will open and close the harvester but nothing has ever been read into the buffer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you send the output to Elasticsearch or Logstash?
If you send it to Logstash, you might want to do the split there with the delimiter option:

```
codec => json_lines {
  delimiter => "<some_sequence>"
}
```

Comment: The crux of the problem is that Filebeat is unable to send the output to Elasticsearch or Logstash. It will not pick up the event as the line does not end in a CR/new line. So, whilst Logstash does have a way of handling this, I cannot get it to Logstash and I need something more lightweight than Logstash installed on this endpoint i.e. Filebeat (or some other shipper).

Comment: You can send the output using "multiline" with patterns like "*" and then use the "delimiter" option in Logstash as I suggested